# Comment exprimer « cling tightly » (pour une famille) ?

Tags: anglais, demande-de-mot

Il s'agit d'une famille qui « cling tightly to one another ». Ils vivent sous le même toit, enfants, ados et adultes, mais ont une vie assez ballottée.

Le sens est très clair, mais le français résiste.

Sont-ils :
"très attachés les uns aux autres"
"étroitement liés les uns aux autres"
"accrochés les uns aux autres"
"étroitement liés"
"très soudés"
ou quelle autre solution encore ?

Comment: @kantx le contexte et les phrases environnantes s-il te plait

Comment: @kantx context please, it is necessary for the answer

Comment: to cling tightly veut dire (bien) s'accrocher dans le sens de désespération. Un enfant s'accroche à une mère lorsqu'il a peur. C'est pareil ici. Aucun doute.

Comment: Une famille dont les membres s'accrochent les uns aux autres. Just like: he clung tightly to his mother> He s'est accroché à sa maman.

Answer (score 2):

Au Québec, on parlerait d'une famille tissée «serrée» ( = «tightly woven»). Je n'ai aucune idée si cette expression est utilisée ailleurs.

Comment: Plutôt [_tricotée serrée_](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4036) que _tissée_...

Comment: Je devine le sens mais ça ne se dirait pas en France.

Comment: La traduction est: les membres de la famille s'accrochent les uns aux autres. Voilà.

Comment: J'avais mis une réponse et on me l'a enlevé. En disant que je n'avais pas expliqué... J'ai même donné un exemple en français. Alors, please....remettez ma réponse et je verrais si je pourrais l'améliorer.

Comment: @comet hapax d'ajax OK, j'ai bien compris. Et je vois qu'encore une fois la traduction que j'ai proposé a été enlevé. You know what? I'm done here. On me cite Reverso/Collins pour la traduction. On peut traduire cling tightly par BIEN s'accrocher ou bien par s'accrocher BIEN FORT. Encore une fois, ma réponse était la seule qui s'approcher du sens. Par ailleurs, on pourrait très bien dire que s'accrocher BIEN FORT c'est: to cling VERY tightly to. Le bien me suffit, à moi. Donc, ici on ne peut pas s'en sortir. Et ce n'est pas du tout se serrer les coudes. Link that. :)

Comment: Une famille tissée ou serrée (comme on nous indique pour le Québec)  est simplement la traduction de **a tightly knit family***. Not a family whose members cling tightly to one another. Ce n'est pas la même chose du tout.

Comment: @comet hapax d'ajax tricotée serrée, je vous signale est une traduction mot à mot de l'anglais tightly knit family. Je l'avais mal recopié la prémière fois. Je ne pense pas qu'il faille en savoir plus. Et puis, il ne s'agit pas de m'aider...plutôt le OP (ou PO?). Enfin il faut les membres de la famille pour arriver à: to cling tightly together.

Comment: Il parait qu'au Québec l'origine des expressions est très important...Personellement, cela m'est égale mais je suis venue ici et je lis un tas de réponses complètement à côté de la plaque...alors, on se pose la question....on se pose bien la question....de savoir pourquoi la mienne ne s'y lit plus....alors qu'elle était la meilleure, point de vue sens...

Answer (score 1):

Pour reformuler vos propositions :

> - Une famille soudée dont les membres sont très proches les uns des autres.
> - Une famille soudée dont chaque membre est très lié aux autres.

Dans une famille nombreuse, ou plusieurs familles réunis par une parenté proche :

> - Une *tribu* très solide.

S'il ne s'agit que des enfants,

> - Une *fratrie* inséparable, si les liens familiaux prédominent;
> - Une *fratrie fusionnelle*, si les contacts émotionnels sont très puissants.

Mais il faudrait avoir le contexte réel, "l'ambiance" du texte pour proposer des transpositions plus ciblée ou plus pittoresque.

---

***EDIT***

On peut traduire « We clung tightly to one another. » par :

> Nous nous serrons très fort les coudes.
>
> Nous sommes inséparables.
>
> Chacun de nous défend les autres (si le contexte est difficile).
>
> Un pour tous, tous pour un (devise de la Suisse et des mousquetaires).

Comment: Le contexte est celui d'une famille nombreuse qui n'arrête pas de changer de domicile. Malgré cela, les cinq enfants "cling tightly to one another". Les formules que vous proposez sont intéressantes mais sont trop construites pour être insérées dans un texte écrit très au fil de l'eau. C'est toute la difficulté : il faut de l'immédiateté, quelque chose de très verbal, sans être non plus du tout familier ou relâché.

Comment: @kantx -- S'il s'agit des cinq enfants : "La fratrie [ou la famille] est devenue inséparable en résistant à moult déménagements", "Les cinq enfants furent de plus en plus soudés par le nombre ahurissant de déménagements" permet de montrer la progression dans le renforcement de liens affectifs face au aléas de la vie.

Answer (score -1):

[*Se serrer les coudes*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/se_serrer_les_coudes) semble être une expression appropriée pour cet usage :

- « rester ensemble, rester solidaire, s'entraider » selon le site [sensagent](http://dictionnaire.sensagent.com/se%20serrer%20les%20coudes/fr-fr/)
- « unis, former un bloc » selon [langue française](http://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/40732).

On pourrait donc formuler la phrase suivante :

> Il s'agit d'une famille qui se serre les coude. Ils vivent sous le même toit, enfants, ados et adultes, mais ont une vie assez ballottée.

Cela rejoint le sens d'une famille soudée face aux épreuves de la vie courante.

Pour prendre en compte la remarque de Gilles, on retrouve bien un lien émotionnel dans cette Une du journal Le Monde : [« Se serrer les coudes face à l'angoisse »](http://www.lemonde.fr/economie/article/2015/11/20/se-serrer-les-coudes-face-a-l-angoisse_4814203_3234.html).

Comment: Se serrer les coudes, c'est s'entraider, ça n'implique pas de lien émotionnel contrairement à l'expression à traduire.

Comment: @Gilles Je conteste absolument votre remarque. Selon moi l'expression se serrer les coudes implique évidemment un lien émotionnel qui n'existe pas dans "s'entraider".

Comment: @Gilles : est-ce que les sens proposés par l'OP : "très attachés les uns aux autres" "étroitement liés les uns aux autres" "accrochés les uns aux autres" "étroitement liés" "très soudés" comportent des "liens émotionnels" ? Absolument pas. Des détenus peuvent être attachés les uns aux autres par des menottes. Etroitement liés par le profil de leurs victimes. Très soudés peut se dire de fils électriques.

Comment: Je ne comprends pas pourquoi ma réponse, la seule qui était bien est partie dans le ciel bleu. A family whose members cling tightly together c'est une famille dont les membres s'accrochent les uns aux autres.

Comment: @Kii : vous mêlez et cumulez volontairement les sens littéraux et figurés de ces expressions, c'est habile, péremptoire et peu éclairant. "est-ce que les sens proposés par l'OP : "très attachés les uns aux autres" "étroitement liés les uns aux autres" "accrochés les uns aux autres" "étroitement liés" "très soudés" comportent des "liens émotionnels" ?" Réponse : c'est l'évidence. ;-)

Comment: @Gilles : I'm with you…

Comment: @Lambie : s'accrochent-ils en rappel sur la face nord du Kilimandjaro ? ;-)

Comment: No, when you rappel, you are not clinging to the face of a rock you are climbing. Ou on s'accroche ou on monte ou on descend en rappel. On ne peut pas faire les deux en même temps....

Comment: Se serrer les coudes is not to cling tightly to one another. Il parait que personne ici parle les deux langues, vraiement bien. Se serrer les coudes serait to stick together. As a family, we stick together. Par ailleurs, se serrer les coudes ne donnent pas l'idée de peur, ou angoisse etc. comme cling tightly to.

Comment: @Lambie je suis d'accord que "se serrer les coudes" n'est pas directement lié à une sensation de peur ou d'angoisse cependant comme dans l'article du Monde qui est cité, c'est une réaction possible face à la peur et l'angoisse. Selon moi, et vu le contexte c'est l'une des meilleurs traductions

Comment: Bof, pour moi, je sens un manque de connaissance des deux langues. Alors, je me retire de la discussion. Trop fatiguant. Je ne voudrais pas perdre mes éperons (comme on dit en espagnole)...:) Bonne journée (ou soirée) à vous. Se serrer les coudes< to stick together.